# Calling JavaScript function from <a href>

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to call a `JavaScript` function with parameter as `php` script using the following code

`<a href="javascript: submitform(<?php echo $job; ?>)">submit</a>`

any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: you can't Javascript is client side. and php is server side. they won't understand each other on their own.

Comment: @ejay_francisco I wrote the javascript inside the php file but the problem is with the parameter, how its should be written

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="submitform(<?php echo $job; ?>);"> submit</a>
```

OR

```
var job  ='';
job  = <?php echo $job; ?>;
<a href="#" onclick="submitform(job);"> submit</a>
```

Comment: If `$job = "); alert('lol hax'"` then you're in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If `$job` is anything but a number, your code will fail.

To drop a PHP variable into a JavaScript context, you *must* use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode). Since you're in an HTML attribute, you *must also* use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

So:

```
<a href="javascript:submitform(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($job));?>);">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use any of this two

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="submitform(<?php echo $job; ?>);">submit</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="submitform(<?php echo $job; ?>);">submit</a>
```

Comment: What if `$job` contains an apostrophe? Or a double-quote? XSS alert!

Answer (score 0):

You can write in php directly

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="#" onclick="javascript: submitform(\"'+$job+'\")">submit</a>';
?>
```